# Construct an operator using outer product of two MPS using TeNPy

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, computational-physics, software, tensor-network

I am fairly new to Matrix Product State (MPS) formalism, but I've used Density Matrix Renormalisation Group (DMRG) techniques before. I'm learning to use [TeNPy](https://tenpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and a particular problem I am trying to tackle is given a state $| s \rangle$ as a [MPS](https://tenpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/tenpy.networks.mps.MPS.html), is there an easy way to construct the operator $$\hat{U}_s = 2 |s\rangle \langle s| -I,$$ where $I$ is the identity.

One possible solution I can think of is to loop over the physical indices, and use the [get_B() method](https://tenpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/tenpy.networks.mps.MPS.html#tenpy.networks.mps.MPS.get_B) to find the local matrices, and then taking the local tensor products. I was curious whether there might be an easier way to do this?

Comment: "Construct" in which way? Apply it to a given MPS? Apply it to a general vector? Construct the full matrix?

Comment: Thank you. I am attempting to apply $\hat{U}_s$ to a given MPS.

Comment: Well, then the result is just the difference of the original MPS and |s>, weighted with their overlap.

Comment: @Qmechanic MPS = matrix product state, TeNPy is a software package for tensor-network methods. I haven't thought about tenpy in a while, but it seems like this is something that would be 100x more efficient without TenPy. TenPy is nice, but it designed to be fool tolerant. Custom codes will be more efficient. But you probably want to make and compress a matrix product operator (MPO). Unsurprisingly, what Norbert says is probably most efficient.

Comment: I've written the code following Norbert's method at the moment. As I get more comfortable with tensor networks, I will attempt to write my own functions. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think the real question is why you want to do this, or rather what you actually want to achieve. It sounds like a somewhat odd thing to do, certainly from a condensed matter context. Do you want to simulate Grover?

Comment: @Norbert Indeed, I am attempting to do so.

Comment: A follow-up question, is it possible to follow the same strategy if $|s \rangle$ (and the MPS I'm trying to apply $\hat{U}_s$ on) are infinite matrix product states? [From the warning on iMPS here](https://tenpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/tenpy.networks.mps.html), I suspect a different strategy might be necessary.